# Task Scheduler cannot run ps1 in background

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple .ps1 file to unmap a network drive

```
# NAS
Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0
If (Test-Path N:) {
    Net Use "N:" /delete
}
```

I have another script to mount that drive manually, and I want to set up a task in the Task Scheduler to periodically check whether the drive is mapped and unmap it if it is.

The script works.

I created a simple task, and it works with the following parameters checked:

```
Run only when user is logged on
Hidden
Arguments: -windowstyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\MyScripts\UnmapNAS.ps1
```

The issue is that when executing, the popup still flashes - albeit very quickly. I do not want it to flash. (eg while I'm typing, it flashes and it skips a letter or two.)

I read that the solution was check "*Run whether user is logged on or not*". I tried, and indeed there is no more popup. However, it does not work and I don't know what's happening or what the error is.
I tried to click "*Run with highest privilege*" too as I am in the Administrator group but it didn't seem to change a thing.

### I found why, not the solution

I use the following command to map the drive:

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("N:", "\\192.168.1.100\NAS", $true, $User, $Password)
```

The drive is mounted for `User`. However, it is not mounted for `NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM`. This means that when the Task Scheduler runs the script, `SYSTEM` cannot find any `N:` drive to unmap.

I read that mapped drive are user specific. So I guess the solution would be to run the `unmapNAS.ps1` as SYSTEM and edit that script to switch to `User` to use the `net use /delete` command.

## Solution

See the accepted answer for the explanation

launcher.vbs :

```
command = "powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\MyScripts\UnmapNAS.ps1"
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run command,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the task as "Run only when user is logged on"
so it can work on the user's mapped drive.
The option of "Run whether user is logged on or not" is to be avoided,
and also  "Run with highest privilege".

The problem is that `powershell.exe` is a console program, so will
create a console window when executed. Using `-WindowStyle Hidden`,
will only hide it very shortly after it starts.

The solution is to start `powershell.exe` as hidden in the first place.

One way to do this is to run the PowerShell command line as hidden
from inside a WSH script.
The script is executed using `wscript.exe` (which is not a console program).

Example script, stored for example in `C:\Scripts\launcher.js`:

```
var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
wshShell.Run('%SystemRoot%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\\Scripts\\myscript.ps1"', 0, false);
```

The command line for the task is:

```
wscript "C:\Scripts\launcher.js"
```

This runs the `launcher.js` script without a console,
which then runs the PowerShell command in a hidden window
(because the `Run` second parameter is `0`).

---

An alternate solution that worked for the poster was to
launch the PowerShell script from a VBScript:
[How to Execute PowerShell Scripts Without Pop-Up Window](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/how-to-execute-powershell-scripts-without-pop-up-window/)

Comment: It did not work out of the box. I don't know why. However I wrote it in VBS using this and it worked https://www.faqforge.com/windows/how-to-execute-powershell-scripts-without-pop-up-window/

I accept your answer as the correct one as you put your finger on the solution, but I don't know whether it could help everybody

Comment: I'm aware of the VBS method, but thought this one is simpler. I added your link to my answer.